# Detecting Webshere MQ Manager is available again

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I have a C# application which reads messages from an WebSphere queue (MQ version 7.5) and submits them to another application which I need to update to cater for the condition when the Queue Manager is stopped or disconnected. I have updated the queue manager properties to add the 'auto-reconnect' option but I am struggling to detect that the queue manager is available again.

My application waits for up to 3 seconds for a message to appear on a queue and then, if no message appears performs other housekeeping checks before looping round and waiting a for a queued message again.

My queue Manager initialization now includes the statement

```
QueueManagerProperties.Add(MQC.CONNECT_OPTIONS_PROPERTY, MQC.MQCNO_RECONNECT);
```

and I can see that if that the QueueManager property IsConnected becomes false when I stop the queue manager on the MQ server. If I try to perform a 'Get' operation from the queue while the Queue Manager is disconnected I get an 'Object not set to an instance' error from the underlying IBM MQ interface library.

However, when I restart the queue manager on the MQ server, the IsConnected option in my application is still false so I am not able to detect when it is safe to try reading messages from the queue again. No matter what I do I can't seem to detect that the queue manager has re-connected so the application never starts reading messages again.

Any advice on what I need to update would be much appreciated.

Comment: Make sure you are connecting via a `Client Channel Definition Table`

Comment: MQ .NET client will attempt to reconnect to queue for default period of 30 minutes. If it fails in that 30 minutes, then application has to issue 'Connect' call again. So after how long your application is issuing 'Get' call?

Comment: In my test environment I attempt the re-connect within 5 minutes. However, I noticed that if I try a 'Get' command while the queue manger is disconnected the underlying IBM library crashes with an 'Object not set to an instance' error. i.e. I can't seem to issue Get commands while the connection to the MQ server is broken.

Answer (score 0):

If automatic client reconnect feature is used, the `Get` call will initiate reconnection to queue manager. While reconnection process is in progress the `Get` will appear to hang. It's an error if the call returns with an exception. Are you at latest fix pack? This error may have been fixed in latest fix pack.